# UITabBarItem Frame changed?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, uitabbarcontroller

I'm Work on `UITabBarController` using xib not storyboard.

In iPhone `UITabBarItem` frame is correct and select item successfully but when we run application on iPad then `UITabBar` frame show iPhone `UITabBar` frame and I'm changing the `UITabBar` frame but the selection of the `UITabBarItem` is not set.
 How we can change the `UITabBarItem`.

Comment: Need to see something more (code, images etc) it's not clear what you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

Check my tab bar code

`self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        self.viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController~ipad" bundle:nil];
        _NavController=[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.viewController];
        tabBar=[[UITabBarController alloc] init];

```
    [[UITabBar appearance] setSelectionIndicatorImage:[[UIImage alloc] init]];
    console=[[ConsoleViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ConsoleViewController~ipad" bundle:nil];
    // console.title=@"Start";
    tagViewObj=[[TagsViewViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"TagsViewViewController~ipad" bundle:nil];
    //tagViewObj.title=@"Tags";
    SettingsObj=[[SettingsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SettingsViewController~ipad" bundle:nil];

UINavigationController *Navcontroller1=[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:console];
UINavigationController *Navcontroller2=[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:tagViewObj];
UINavigationController *Navcontroller3=[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:SettingsObj];

tabBar.viewControllers=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:Navcontroller1,Navcontroller2,Navcontroller3, nil];`
```

please see the image https://i.stack.imgur.com/faAdD.png

Answer (score 0):

Use the `UITabBar` property `itemWidth`

```
self.tabBar.itemWidth = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width/self.viewControllers.count;

@property(nonatomic) CGFloat itemWidth NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(7_0) UI_APPEARANCE_SELECTOR;
```